# Method reference inside synchronized expression

Tags: java, java-8, method-reference

Sorry guys, but I can not understand, on which object is `synchronized` block inside `sync()` method is synchronized:

```
public class TestLambda {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    sync();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }

    static void sync() throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized ((Runnable)TestLambda::new) {
            System.out.println("inside");
            Thread.sleep(1000L);
        }
    }
}
```

If on method reference object, why I can not just write: 
`synchronized (TestLambda::new)` ? (it will be compile-time-error).

Any ideas?

**UPD**: Just in case: it is **really** synchronized

**UPD-2**: For those, who is doubting, simple example:

```
C:\sandbox\research\learn8\src>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin\"javac TestLambda.java
TestLambda.java:27: error: method reference not expected here
    public class Test { { synchronized (Test::new) { System.out.println("sync"); } } }
                                        ^
1 error
```

Comment: What kind of syntax is this ?? something new in Java 8 ?

Comment: @Antoniossss yes, it is `java-8` as I marked in tags

Comment: I can get your `Test` class to compile by casting the method reference to `Runnable`.

Comment: @rgettman Sure, as I wrote in the main part of question, the question **why?** and **what is it?**

Comment: `TestLambda::new` what is it?

Comment: @Antoniossss Are you joking? :) It is method reference from `java 8`

Comment: I have feeling, that this code is not synchronized at all.

Comment: @Antoniossss  you have a bad feeling. Just run it and see

Comment: This is a terrible idea, because lambda expressions and method references do not evaluate to objects with predictable identity, and therefore you may well be locking on a random object, as if you'd said `synchronized (new Object()) {...}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's see the below 2 assignments:

```
Supplier<TestLambda> supp = TestLambda::new;
Runnable runnable = TestLambda::new;
```

both of them compiles fine. Basically because a lambda or a method reference can be compatible to multiple functional interfaces. That means, merely writing `TestLambda::new` doesn't tell us the exact runtime type of the object created. Which interface to instantiate is determined based on target type. And that target type should always be a functional interface, which is not the case in the below statement:

```
synchronized(TestLambda::new) {
}
```

So, the compiler wouldn't allow it, as the runtime wouldn't be able to decide which functional interface to instantiate. You give that information by casting the method reference to `Runnable`. So, in the below statement:

```
synchronized((Runnable) TestLambda::new) {
}
```

the runtime will instantiate an object of class implementing the `Runnable` interface. In a sense, the casting gives a concreteness to the method reference.

To give a vague idea, this could somewhat be translated like this:

```
class RuntimeClass implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        TestLambda testLambda = new TestLambda();
    }
}

synchronized(new RuntimeClass()) {
}
```

*P.S:* Actual instance of the `RuntimeClass` will be singleton (as we're using a stateless method expression)  -- My original incorrect statement

*P.P.S*: As noted from comments by @Stuart, it is not guaranteed whether for a lambda or method reference, a new instance will be created or the same will be returned. So, you shouldn't synchronize on them.

Comment: And on which object it will be synchronized?

Comment: @Andremoniy On the object of a class implementing `Runnable`.

Comment: So the result is in synchronizing on new object of `TestLambda implements Runnable` ??? Moreover is that block really synchronized (as always will be different object to lock montor on)?

Comment: @Antoniossss Of course that is a synchronized block. And no, `TestLambda::new` wouldn't create new lambda object every time that block is executed. Stateless lambdas and method references are translated to singleton objects.

Comment: Could you point me to some materials explaining why no new object is created on every invokation? And yeah, if it is the same object every time, than it is synchronized. What instance is taken then?

Comment: @Antoniossss You could go through the Oracle tutorial or JLS. Just google it. Instance will be still of `Runnable` implementing class, but that would be singleton instance.

Comment: @RohitJain  Than your edit is not correct, as code will not be synchronized - no shared object for monitor locking.

Comment: @Antoniossss As I wrote there - "Vague Idea". Definitely I didn't intended to give exact implementation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74456/discussion-between-antoniossss-and-rohit-jain).

Comment: There are no guarantees about whether `(Runnable) TestLambda::new` will return the same or different instances each time it's called. The `synchronized` construct will lock on whatever instance it's given, but since you can't guarantee anything about whether it's the same instance, synchronizing won't have the desired effects of mutual exclusion, memory visibility, etc. Don't synchronize on a lambda or method reference.

Comment: @StuartMarks God!! And I always thought stateless lambdas return same instance :(

Comment: It’s worth noting that the JRE even has the freedom to return the same instance for different lambda expressions which might lead to the situation that such code has *more* contention than necessary, up to spurious deadlocks. It’s similar to synchronizing on the result of auto-boxing, the results are unpredictable. It might even be the case that within an implementation that returns a singleton, the hotspot optimizer still elides the synchronization as it knows that there is no guaranty about it, as it does for purely local objects.

Answer (score 3):

> JLS 14.19. The `synchronized` Statement
>
> ```
> SynchronizedStatement:
>     synchronized ( Expression ) Block
> ```
>
> The type of *Expression* must be a reference type, or a compile-time error occurs.

---

> JLS 15.13.2. Type of a Method Reference
>
> A method reference expression is compatible in an assignment context, invocation context, or casting context with a target type T if T is a functional interface type (§9.8) and the expression is congruent with the function type of the ground target type derived from T.

The above two stipulations should paint the picture: the `synchronized` statement takes any reference-typed expression, and a method reference is *compatible* with any target reference type T which is a functional interface. Note that `Object` does not satisfy this.

In other words, there is a degree of freedom left: which exactly reference type should the method reference be compatible with? This freedom must be taken away by an explicit type cast, which forces it into that particular type. Only then has the type of the whole expression become known.

Comment: *degree of freedom* -> reminds me of deadly Chemistry classes from my school times...

Comment: Really, chemistry? Where do DOFs enter into chemistry? I have a faint memory that it may do with thermal capacity of materials.

Comment: Yes, somewhat related to that.. The possible movement of particles when heated (Digging into my faint memory too :P)

Comment: There was something about having vs. not having rotational DOFs that had interesting consequences. But details elude me... in other words, time for wikipedia :)